# openconnect on Ubuntu 14.04LTS :"XML response has no "auth" node"

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ubuntu-14.04, juniper

I ran `openconnect` to connect to Juniper as following:

```
$ openconnect --version
OpenConnect version v5.02
Using GnuTLS. Features present: PKCS#11, TOTP software token, DTLS (using OpenSSL)


sudo openconnect -v -u=myuser --no-xmlpost --no-proxy https://myserver

Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 07:24:03 GMT
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires: -1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
HTTP body chunked (-2)
XML response has no "auth" node
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Could you fix this? What does `XML response has no "auth" node` mean?

Comment: For me it means it failed to connect to vpn :(

Comment: I ended up using `openvpn` ^^

Comment: @StefanR.Falk hello! is openvpn working for you from `ubuntu` with `juniper`? can you post please an example command you use?

Comment: Have you tried to set UserGroup for the connection? Usually it's path after the host name like https://my.host.name/myUserGroup.

Comment: How are you authenticating? You shouldn't be getting a WebVPN cookie before entering a password or other auth (and you're not using XML to auth if you've got `--no-xmlpost` in there).

Comment: Does the router have a password? Try to omit the username portion...

Answer (score 1):

Please update your open connect to latest version for most such this cases issue will be solved

your version is not compatible